# Java : How to assign Json formated String to Java String?

Tags: java, json

I have a big json string which i will be getting as a request from the UI , which will be converted to a String and parsed .

I want to simulate the similar environment for testing locally  , so for this purpose i captured the JSon format.

Currently i am manually adding  "/" to this big json string .

Is there any other way to achieve this ??

For example i got this json

```
{"age":29,"messages":["msg 1","msg 2","msg 3"],"name":"Preethi"}
```

and converted that into

```
 String str = "{\"age\":\"29\",\"messages\":[\"msg 1\",\"msg 2\",\"msg 3\"],\"name\":\"mkyong\"}";
```

Is there any other way to achieve this ??

Comment: Store you test JSON in files, load as resource?

Comment: Ya , got your point , but dont want to use Object Mapper and all .

Comment: You don't need to use an Object Mapper in order to load the json from a file into a string.

Answer (score 0):

On the client-side, do a search and regex "replace all" of double-quotes into single quotes on the desired form field before actually sending the request.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, Java doesn't have [verbatim string literals](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691090.aspx).

If you want a Java-like (and Java-VM-based) language that *does*, however, you might want to look at [Groovy](http://groovy.codehaus.org) which has [various forms of string literal](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Strings+and+GString).

Answer (score 0):

we have in build method to convert jsonObject to string. Why don't you use that.

```
 JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
 json.toString();
```